# How to migrate datalake gen1 datasets to datalake gen2 in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Recently for our solution we are requested to upgrade to datalake gen 2 from gen 1
However i am able to load the folders and files from gen 1 to gen2 using azure data factory but in existing data factory we have multiple datasets associated with datalake gen1.

Can anyone suggest me how to change datasets from gen 1 to gen 2 in azure data factory?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-from-gen1

Answer (score 0):

You can be able to load the folders and files from gen 1 to gen2 using azure data factory.

In Data Factory, you can change the exist datasets like this:

Data Factory-->Author-->Dataset-->Choose the exist dataset-->New:

[image]

New linked service:
[image]

Then the dataset will changed linked to Azure Data Lake Gen 2, just choose the file you have loaded from Gen 1.

Don't forget Publish the changes.

[image]

Some limits are that you must edit the multiple datasets one by one for now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don’t we have provision to change in arm template?

Comment: @PradeepKaja I'm not sure, I can't answer you for now. You could test it in template by yourself. What I can do is post the feasible solution which I have tested for you.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.